# Youtube video upload in python results in auth issues (401, 403)

Tags: python, youtube-data-api

Trying to upload a bunch of videos (200) on a youtube channel. Needs to be done programatically to set titles, categories, retrieve files, and store IDs of uploaded videos.

This is the code I am testing:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# Loading credentials and specifying channel ID
credentials_file = 'yt-uploader-python-495b4c622ddf.json'

# Authenticate with the YouTube API using the credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(credentials_file, scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'])
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

# Set video metadata
video_metadata = {
    'snippet': {
        'title': 'Test video',
        'description': 'Test video Description',
        'tags': ['my tag'],
        'categoryId': '22',  # Specify the category (e.g., 'Entertainment')
    },
    'status': {
        'privacyStatus': 'private',  # Set video privacy (public, private, unlisted)
    }
}

# Specify the path to the video file you want to upload
video_file_path = 'my folder/my video.mp4'
# Upload the video
media = MediaFileUpload(video_file_path)

upload_response = youtube.videos().insert(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=video_metadata,
    media_body=media
).execute()

# After uploading the video, store the video ID
video_id = upload_response['id']

# Construct the video URL
video_url = f'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={video_id}'
```

The execution resulted in a timeout, then in a 401 error, then in a 403 error. Unsure about where to bang my head.

As I got 3 different errors I am deeply unsure about the cause of this problem. I suspect this could be an authentication issue.

Comment: Can you provide the full text of each of the errors, including the traceback?